# On the $\pi$-induced pushforward of a tensor field on $TM$

Tags: differential-geometry, tangent-bundle, pushforward

A short informal premise. As far as I understand, given a smooth map between manifolds $f: M \to N$ and a smooth vector field $X: M \to TM$, the pushforward $f_* X$ only defines in general a vector field along $f$, that is a map $f_* X: M \to TN$ such that $\pi_N \circ f_* X = f$. The pushforward $f_* X$ defines a unique vector field $Y: N \to TN$ if $f$ is a diffeomorphism or, more generally, if $f$ is surjective and $X$ and $Y$ are $f$-related, that is $f_*(m) X_m=Y_{f(m)}$ for each $m \in M$. The latter condition is fulfilled whenever $X$ is $f$-projectable, that is $f_*(m) X_m=Y_n$ for each $m \in f^{-1}(\{n\})$, where $f^{-1}$ denotes the inverse image.

These considerations can be applied to the case $f \equiv \pi_M : TM \to M$ and $X$ a vector field on $TM$. Since $\pi_M$ is surjective, if $X$ is projectable, then $\pi_{M*} X$ is a well-defined vector field on $M$ (the “projection” of $X$ onto the base manifold). In canonical local coordinates the most general vector field $X$ in $TM$ can be written as:

$$X=A^a(x,v) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^a} + B^a(x,v) \frac{\partial}{\partial v^a}$$

Since $(\pi_{M*} X)\psi :=X(\psi \circ \pi_{M})$ for $\psi :M \to \Bbb{R}$ (where the relation is to be intended pointwise), it seems to me that $X$ is $\pi_M$-projectable (and so $\pi_{M*} X$ is a vector field on $M$) iff $A^a$ only depends on $x$, that is for fields of the form

$$X=A^a(x) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^a} + B^a(x,v) \frac{\partial}{\partial v^a}$$

Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Thank you. The reason I asked is that I'm confused about the definition of the vertical lift $A^{\uparrow}$ of a ${1 \choose p}$ tensor _field_ $A$ on $M$, namely:

$$A^{\uparrow}(X_1, ..., X_p) := (A(\pi_{M*} X_1,...,A(\pi_{M*} X_p))^\uparrow$$

where $X_i$, $i=1,...,p$, are vector _fields_ on $M$ and the vertical lift of a vector $w \in T_m M$ at the "point" $v \in T_m M$ is  

$$ (w^\uparrow )_v := \left.\frac{d}{dt} \right|_0 (v+t w) $$

Here the $X_i$ are general (not necessarily projectable) fields, so $\pi_{M*} X_i$ are not vector fields on $M$. How can I feed them to $A$?

Comment: The value of $A(Y_1,\dots,Y_p)$ at $x \in M$ depends only on the values of $Y_1, \dots, Y_p$ at $x$. Thus, if $v_1, \dots, v_p \in T_xM$ we can define $A(v_1, \dots, v_p) = A(Y_1, \dots, Y_p)$ where $Y_i$ is any vector field of $M$ such that ${Y_i}_x = v_i$. So it makes sense to feed the tangent vectors ${\pi_M}_*X_i$ to $A$.

Comment: I understand the definition holds on a pointwise basis, but - sorry if I insist - how should I handle $\pi_{M*} X$ in case of a concrete computation? For example, if $A \equiv \hat{1} = dx^a \otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}$ and $X=A^a(x,v) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^a} + B^a(x,v) \frac{\partial}{\partial v^a}$, is it possible to write $\hat{1}^\uparrow(X) = (\pi_{M*} X)^\uparrow = A^a(x,v) \frac{\partial}{\partial v^a}$? This is apparently a map $TTM \to TM$, that is a vector field along $\pi_M$.

Comment: The last sentence was referred to $\pi_{M*} X = A^a (x,v) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}$, sorry but the system doesn't allow to edit comments after 5 minutes since their submission.

Comment: Your computation of $\hat{1}^{\uparrow}(X)$ seems right. I didn't understand what you meant in the last sentence.