# Pushforward, tangent map, vertical endomorphism and all that

Tags: differential-geometry, fiber-bundles, pushforward

I've already posted a similar question a couple of times, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2821170/on-the-pi-induced-pushforward-of-a-tensor-field-on-tm) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4804423/push-forward-of-a-vector-field-on-the-tangent-bundle-tm-onto-m-under-the-bundle), without receiving a fully clarifying answer, so I post it again, trying to be more specific.

Suppose you have a smooth surjective submersion between smooth manifolds: $f: N \rightarrow M \equiv f(N)$, with $\dim N >\dim M$. The tangent map $Tf: TN \rightarrow TM$ is defined pointwise in terms of $f_\ast $, the pushforward by $f$. In local coordinates, if $(x, v)$ is a point in $TN$, corresponding to the tangent vector
$ v = \left. v^a \frac{\partial}{\partial x^a }\right|_x \in T_x N$,
then

$$(Tf)(x,v) = (y, w) := (f(x),f_{\ast,x}v), $$
where $w := f_{\ast,x}v \in T_{f(x)}M$ is such that $(f_{\ast,x}v)g = v (g \circ f)$ for any smooth $g: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.
Of course, since $f$ is surjective but not injective, if $f(x)=f(x') =y$, then the images of the two points $(x,v)$ and $(x', v')$ correspond to two generally different tangent vectors to $M$ at the same point $y$. Thus, $Tf$ cannot map the tangent *field* in $X \in \mathcal X(N)$ to a tangent *field* in $Y \in \mathcal X(M)$, unless $f_{\ast,x}X_x = Y_{y}$ for any $x$ in the inverse image of $y$, i.e. $\forall x \in f^{-1}(y)$ $(Tf)(x, X(x)) = (y, Y)$. In this case, $Y = f_\ast X$ and the two fields are said to be $f$-related.

Now, let us specialize these considerations to the case of the tangent bundle $\pi_M: TM \rightarrow M$, that is let us pose $N \equiv TM$, $ f \equiv \pi_M$, with $\pi_M$ the bundle projection, which is indeed a surjective submersion. Obviously, assuming $\dim M = n$, we have $\dim TM = 2n$ and, if $x$ identifies a point in $M$ in local coordinates, a point $\xi \in TM$ can be locally parametrized as $\xi = (x, u)$, where $u \in T_x M$. The tangent map $T\pi_M: TTM \rightarrow TM$ maps a generic point $\Xi = (\xi, \eta) \equiv ((x,u),(v,w)) \in TTM$ to the point $\xi' = (x', u') = (\pi_M(\xi), \pi_{M*,\xi} \eta) = (x, \pi_{M*,(x,u)}(v,w)) \in TM$, where the tangent vector $\eta \in T_\xi TM$, $\eta = \eta^A \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi^A}\right|_\xi
$,
can also be conveniently expressed, in terms of coordinates adapted to the local trivialization of $TTM$ as $U \subseteq M \times \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$, in the form:

$$
\eta =  v^a\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}\right\vert_{(x,u)} +  w^a \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial u^a}\right\vert_{(x,u)}.
$$
The second term of $\xi'$, $u' = \pi_{M*,\xi} \eta$, can be determined by requiring that, for any function $g \in \mathcal F(M)$, $(\pi_{M*,\xi}\eta) g = \eta(\pi_M^\ast g) \equiv \eta(g \circ \pi_M)$. We note that $g \circ \pi_M$ is a generic function in $\mathcal F(TM)$ that is "constant along the fiber", i.e. depends only on $x$ and not on $u$: $(g \circ \pi_M)(x,u) = g(x)$. So, $u' = \pi_{M*,\xi}\eta \equiv v = v^a \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}\right\vert_x$ and the action of the tangent map can be written as $(T\pi_M)(x,u,v,w) = (x,v)$. This is to be contrasted with the action of the bundle projection map $\pi_{TM}$ that enters into the definition of the (second) tangent bundle $\pi_{TM}: TTM \rightarrow TM$. Indeed, $\pi_{TM}(x,u,v,w) = \pi_{TM}(\xi,\eta) = \xi = (x,u)$. As a consequence, $\pi_M \circ \pi_{TM} = \pi_M \circ T\pi_M: TTM \rightarrow M$.

After this very long and tedious introduction, let me explain what my concern is. The latter is related to the possibility to map vector *fields* in $TTM$ to vector *fields* in $TM$ via $T\pi_M$. The point is the following: since locally we can write $x = \pi_M(\xi)$, that is $x^a = \xi^a$, $a=1, \dots, n$, the Jacobian of this transformation is $\pi_{M*,\xi} = \frac{\partial x^a}{\partial \xi^A}(\xi) \equiv (\delta^a_b, 0^a_b)$, $a,b = 1, \dots, n$, $A=1, \dots, 2n$. This is a *constant* $n \times 2n$ matrix of rank $n$, consisting of the unit $n \times n$ matrix followed by $n \times n$ zeroes. By applying this Jacobian to a generic vector field $X \in \mathcal(TTM)$, which can be written locally as:

$$
X =  v^a(x,u)\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}\right\vert_{(x,u)} +  w^a (x,u)\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial u^a}\right\vert_{(x,u)},
$$

I get $v^a(x,u)\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}\right\vert_{x}$, which is $not$ a well-defined vector field on $M$, unless $v^a(x, u) \equiv v^a(x)$. In other words, it seems to me that $X$ is $\pi_M$-related to $Y = v^a(x)\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}\right\vert_{x}$ iff $ X =  v^a(x)\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}\right\vert_{(x,u)} +  w^a (x,u)\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial u^a}\right\vert_{(x,u)}.$

In summary, it looks like we can project onto $M$ via $T\pi_M$ only a well-specified subset of all possible vector fields on $TM$. Nonetheless, in the study of Lagrangian dynamical systems, one introduces the so-called *vertical endomorphism* $S$. This is a rank-2 mixed vector field on $TM$, $S \in \mathcal T_1^1(TM)$, defined pointwise as $S = \mathrm{vl} \circ T\pi_M$, where $\mathrm{vl}$ is the vertical lift, which maps vectors in $M$ to vertical vectors in $TM$. In local coordinates:
$$
\mathrm{vl}\left(v^a\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}\right\vert_{x}\right) = v^a\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial u^a}\right\vert_{(x,u)}.
$$
Without entering into much detail, the vertical endomorphism tensor field can be written locally as $S = dx^a \otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial u^a}$ and maps tensor *fields* on $TM$ into vertical tensor *fields* on $TM$, that is, as I understand it, the generic field
$$
X =  v^a(x,u)\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}\right\vert_{(x,u)} +  w^a (x,u)\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial u^a}\right\vert_{(x,u)},
$$
is mapped by $S$ into the corresponding vertical field
$$
X^{\mathrm{v}} =  v^a(x,u)\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial u^a}\right\vert_{(x,u)}.
$$

This result seems to imply that one first, by means of $T\pi_M$, projects $X$ down to $v^a(x,u)\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}\right\vert_{x}$, whatever it is, and then lifts this intermediate result up to $X^{\mathrm{v}}$.
That this is the case is demonstrated by the following well-known result in Lagrangian analytical mechanics:

$$
S(\Gamma) = \Delta.
$$
Here $\Delta \in \mathcal{X}(TM)$ is the Liouville or dilation field, expressed locally as $\Delta = u^a \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial u^a}\right\vert_{(x,u)}$ and $\Gamma \in \mathcal{X}(TM)$ is any so-called SODE (second-order differential equation) field, written in local coordinates as $\Gamma =  u^a\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}\right\vert_{(x,u)} +  \Gamma^a (x,u)\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial u^a}\right\vert_{(x,u)}$. For SODE fields the components multiplying $\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}\right\vert_{(x,u)}$ are not only dependent on $u$, but do as a matter of fact *coincide* with $u$. So, the action of $S$, and hence of $T\pi_M$, on unrestricted, generic vector fields $X \in \mathcal{X}(TM)$ is perfectly legitimate.

I don't understand how this is possible. Any insight is welcome.

**UPDATE**

Since I received no answers so far, I'll try to elaborate a little bit, so as to stimulate a reply.

First of all, IMHO it is certain that *in general* the map $T\pi_M$, that is the differential of the canonical projection $\pi_M$, does not not send vector fields in $TM$ to vector fields in $M$. Indeed, given the generic vector field $X \in \mathcal{X}(TM)$ in induced coordinates as introduced before, the two vectors
$$
X_1 = v^a(\bar{x},\bar{u}_1)\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}\right\vert_{(\bar{x},\bar{u}_1)} +  w^a (\bar{x},\bar{u}_1)\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial u^a}\right\vert_{(\bar{x},\bar{u}_1)} \equiv 
{v_1}^a\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}\right\vert_{(\bar{x},\bar{u}_1)} +  {w_1}^a \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial u^a}\right\vert_{(\bar{x},\bar{u}_1)}
$$
and
$$
X_2 = v^a(\bar{x},\bar{u}_2)\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}\right\vert_{(\bar{x},\bar{u}_2)} +  w^a (\bar{x},\bar{u}_2)\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial u^a}\right\vert_{(\bar{x},\bar{u}_2)} \equiv 
{v_2}^a\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}\right\vert_{(\bar{x},\bar{u}_2)} +  {w_2}^a \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial u^a}\right\vert_{(\bar{x},\bar{u}_2)},
$$
belonging to two different points of the same fiber ${\pi_M}^{-1}(\bar{x})$, are mapped by $T\pi_M$ onto two different vectors at the *same* point $\bar{x}$ in $M$, namely
$$
X_1 \mapsto {v_1}^a\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}\right\vert_{\bar{x}}, X_2 \mapsto {v_2}^a\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}\right\vert_{\bar{x}}.
$$
Of course, any vector on the same fiber is mapped onto a different vector at the same point in the base space, *unless* the vector field is projectable, that is the components $v^a$ do not depend on $u$ (are constant on the fiber). Only in this case $T\pi_M$ maps (projectable, i.e. not general) vector fields onto vector fields.

Does the definition of the vertical endomorphism, $S:=\mathrm{vl}\circ T\pi_M$ make sense even for general vector fields $X \in \mathcal{X}(TM)$ if applied pointwise?
My temporary answer is: yes, *provided* the vertical lift of the vectors mapped onto $M$ by means of $T\pi_M$ keeps track of the point on the fiber where the original vectors in $TM$ resided.

What I mean is the following. Considering my previous example, in principle the two vectors ${v_1}^a\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}\right\vert_{\bar{x}}$ and ${v_2}^a\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}\right\vert_{\bar{x}}$ can be mapped by $\mathrm{vl}$ to vertical vectors to any point $(\bar{x},u)$ on the fiber over $\bar{x}$. The application of the vertical endomorphism $S$ to $X$ only results in a vertical vector $field$ $X^V \in TM$ if the first vector is mapped by $\mathrm{vl}$ to the point $(\bar{x},\bar{u}_1)$ and the second to $(\bar{x},\bar{u}_2)$ - and so on for all other vectors of the form $v^a(x,u)\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}\right\vert_{x}$ (for given $x$ and $u$) obtained by applying $T\pi_M$ to $X$. Yet, how can the map $\mathrm{vl}$ know which point on the fiber the vector it's lifting comes from? If we work pointwise, components like ${v_1}^a$ and ${v_2}^a$ are no functions, just numbers.

The problem is that all these considerations are absent from the discussion of the vertical endomorphism tensor in any of the reference sources I could consult. This makes me suspect I'm wrong somewhere.

But *where* am I wrong?

Comment: You should include links to your previous posts of this question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I did.

Answer (score 1):

I think the basic answer to your question is that yes, the vertical map $\operatorname{vl}$ does keep track of the point in $TM$ where the original vector lies. More precisely, $S:T(TM)\to T(TM)$ is defined for $X_u \in T_u(TM)$, by
$$
S(X_u) := \operatorname{vl}_u(T_u\pi_M(X_u))
$$
where $T_u\pi_M:T_u(TM)\to T_{\pi(u)} M$ and $\operatorname{vl}_u:T_{\pi(u)}M \to T_u(TM)$ is defined by
$$
\operatorname{vl}_u(v) := \frac{d}{ds}\bigg\vert_{s=0}(u+sv).
$$

Then a vector field $X\in\mathcal{X}(TM)$ is said to be a second-order differential equation if $S(X_u) = \Gamma_u$ for all $u\in TM$. See for example

*Nester, James M.*, [**Invariant derivation of the Euler-Langrange equation**](https://doi.org/10.1088/0305-4470/21/21/003), J. Phys. A 21, No. 21, L1013-L1017 (1988). [ZBL0658.53071](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0658.53071)., p.L1014,

where $S$ is denoted $J$, and is called the almost tangent structure on $TTM$. Or alternatively

*de León, Manuel; Rodrigues, Paulo R.*, Methods of differential geometry in analytical mechanics, North-Holland Mathematics Studies, 158. Amsterdam etc.: North-Holland. x, 483 p. {$} 110.50; Dfl 210.00 (1989). [ZBL0687.53001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0687.53001)., Sections 2.2 and 4.3,

which uses similar notation and terminology to Nester.

Comment: thank you for clarifying this point. It's comforting to know I was not wrong. Thank you also for the references, I didn't know them.

Answer (score 1):

Let me formulate everything for you coordinate-independently, so there is no question whether the maps $T\pi_M$, $\operatorname{vl}$, and $S$ are well-defined globally without restriction.

### Global formulas

First $\pi_M : TM \to M$ is the structure map of the fiber bundle $TM$. Since $TM$ and $M$ are smooth manifolds, we can take the derivative of this map just like any other to obtain a map of vector bundles
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
TTM @>{T\pi_M}>> TM\\
@V{\pi_{TM}}VV @VVV\\
TM @>{\pi_M}>> M
\end{CD}.
$$

Next, for any vector bundle $p : E \to M$ we can define a map of vector bundles
$$
\operatorname{vl} : E \times_M E \to TE.
$$
Let's be very careful about what this means: here we are thinking of $E \times_M E$ as a vector bundle over $E$ via the projection $\operatorname{pr}_1$ onto the first factor, and $TE$ as a vector bundle over $E$ via $\pi_E$. (The notation $E \times_M E$ means the subset of all $(e, e') \in E \times_M E$ such that $p(e) = p(e')$.) Now, what's the definition? Thinking of tangent vectors as equivalence classes of curves (to avoid choosing any coordinates), we define
$$
\operatorname{vl} : (e, e') \mapsto [t \mapsto e + t e'].
$$
That is, for each $(e, e') \in E \times_M E$ there is a curve $\gamma : \mathbb{R} \to E$ defined by $\gamma(t) = e + t e'$, which by taking the equivalence class $[\gamma]$ defines a tangent vector in $T_e E \subset T E$. Of course, in our situation the map $\operatorname{vl}$ is the special case where $E = T M$.

Now, what is the definition of the map $S$? It is not really $S := \operatorname{vl} \circ T \pi_M$ as you say; this forgets too much information. Instead, note that we can form the product of the maps $\pi_{TM} : TTM \to TM$ and $T \pi_M : TTM \to TM$ to obtain a map $(\pi_{TM}, T \pi_M) : TTM \to TM \times_M TM$. This product *is now* composable with $\operatorname{vl}$ to obtain
$$
S : TTM \xrightarrow{(\pi_{TM}, T \pi_M)} TM \times_M TM \xrightarrow{\operatorname{vl}} TTM.
$$

Now everything is well-defined. Let me know if you have any questions.

### Local formulas

If we put coordinates $(x, X)$ on $TM$ and $(x, X, \dot{x}, \dot{X})$ on $TTM$ so that everything is locally trivial, then tracing these definitions through we get
$$
\begin{align*}
\pi_{TM}(x, X, \dot{x}, \dot{X}) &= (x, X)\\
T\pi_{M}(x, X, \dot{x}, \dot{X}) &= (x, \dot{x})\\
\operatorname{vl}((x, X), (x, Y)) &= (x, X, 0, Y)\\
S(x, X, \dot{x}, \dot{X}) &= (x, X, 0, \dot{x}),
\end{align*}
$$
which of course agrees with your formulas.

Comment: Dear Keeley, thank you for your illuminating comment. Just a question: what kind of product is precisely the the product of maps you introduce at the end. It is intuitively clear, but I've never seen it before. In all the sources I consulted, the vertical endomorphism tensor field is defined either pointwise or simply  as $S:=\mathrm{vl}\circ T\pi_M$.

Comment: @RobertoRicci The short answer is that we have taken a so-called *fiber product* of maps. This is a kind of general abstract notion in category theory. The idea is that in our case the object $TM \times_M TM$ (the fiber product of sets, if you like), is completely characterized by a certain defining property. Namely, for any pair of maps $f : X \to TM$ and $g : X \to TM$ from some other space $X$ such that $\pi_M(f(X)) = \pi_M(g(X))$ for all $X$ there exists a unique $(f, g) : X \to TM \times_M TM$. This is an example of what is called a *universal property*.

Comment: (In general, one doesn't have to take the fiber product of an object with itself, and we don't have to be dealing at all with spaces, but could instead have groups, rings, vector spaces, etc.) Fiber products come up a bit when considering the sort of formalism you have been thinking about, because they play nicely with vector bundles (this is really because they are basically the same as the pullback of vector bundles).

Comment: To answer your second question, the reason why the notation $S:=\operatorname{vl}\circ T\pi_M$ can be justified by authors is that if we allow some notational gymnastics we can do the following: fix a vector field $\xi$ on $TM$. Then consider the function $S\xi:=\operatorname{vl}(-,T\pi_M(\xi)):TM\to TTM$, i.e. where we have filled in one "slot" of the two arguments to $\operatorname{vl}$, and left the other slot "$-$" empty. The result is that we have a vector field $S\xi$ on $TM$ defined by $(S\xi)\rvert_X:=\operatorname{vl}(X,T\pi_M(\xi\rvert_X))$.

Comment: Then we could call $S\xi$ the vertical projection of $\xi$. The operation of putting $T\pi_M$ in a "slot" of $\operatorname{vl}$ feels a lot like ordinary function composition using "$\circ$", especially when the other slot accepts things in $TM$ and most of our other symbols on the page are implicitly also functions of $TM$ (such as $\xi$ itself was here). In general in differential geometry it is common to suppress variables parameterizing many of the other quantities to avoid hefty notational baggage.

Comment: The price paid is that one must keep these suppressed dependencies in their head. It can also be potentially unclear, as happened here.

Comment: Dear Keeley, thank you. It is much clearer now.